# i have problem understanding difference between two solutions

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

why should i use two swap functions in second and i only one swap function in first

```java
//first one am getting correct answer with only one swap
import java.util.*;
public class stringper
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       String s=sc.next();
       perm(s,0,s.length());
    }
    static void perm(String s,int left,int right)
    {
        if(left==right)
        {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        for(int i=left;i<right;i++)
        {
            s=swap(s,i,left,1);
            perm(s,left+1,right);
        }
    }
    static String swap(String s,int i,int j)
    {
        char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
        char temp=ch[i];
        ch[i]=ch[j];
        ch[j]=temp;
        s=new String(ch);
        return s;
    }
}
```

```java
//in the second code am getting correct answer with two swap functions
import java.util.*;
public class stringper
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       String s=sc.next();
       int nums[]={1,2,3};
       perm(nums,0,nums.length);
    }
    static void perm(int[] nums,int left,int right)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<nums.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(nums[k]);
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        if(left==right)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> l1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            {
                //l1.add(nums[i]);
            }
            //l.add(l1);
        }
        for(int i=left;i<right;i++)
        {
            nums=swap(nums,i,left);
            perm(nums,left+1,right);
            nums=swap(nums,i,left);
        }
    }
    static int[] swap(int[] nums,int i,int j)
    {
        int temp=nums[i];
        nums[i]=nums[j];
        nums[j]=temp;
        for(int k=0;k<nums.length;k++)
        {
            nums[k]=nums[k];
        }
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should run the code with a debugger, step over the code with some simple input and see what is going on in both cases. Or you could put in some more `print` statements and try to analyze the output.

Comment: in the first version, `swap` has 3 arguments, but you call it using 4

Comment: it is mistake but do you know the answer